# Set Query with a case statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to execute this query

But I get a syntax error

Running MS SQL Management Studio

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.

**My Query**

```
update [Test$ABC]
Set [Unit Price] =(

CASE WHEN [Item No_]= '12345' THEN '445'

CASE WHEN [Item No_]= '67890' THEN '645'

END

)

where [Item No_] in ('12345','67890')
and [Sales Start Date]='01/Apr/19'
and [Store No_]=''
```

Comment: Why do you call it item *number* but use it as a string ('12345')? Why do you call it store *number* but use it as a string ('')? Why is the price a string ('445')? Why is the date a string ('01/Apr/19')? Either you have a horrible database or an inappropriate query or both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Case repeated twice  one expression is enough for your requirement

```
update [Test$ABC]
Set [Unit Price] =(
CASE WHEN [Item No_]= '12345' THEN '445'
     WHEN [Item No_]= '67890' THEN '645'
END
)
where [Item No_] in ('12345','67890')
and [Sales Start Date]='01/Apr/19'
and [Store No_]=''
```

Answer (score 1):

I would write this as:

```
update [Test$ABC]
    set [Unit Price] = (CASE WHEN [Item No_] = 12345 THEN 445
                             WHEN [Item No_] = 67890 THEN 645
                             ELSE [Unit Price]
                        END)
where [Item No_] in (12345, 67890) and
      [Sales Start Date] = '2018-04-01' and
      [Store No_] = '';
```

Notes:

- `[Item No_]` is probably a number, so only compare to numbers.
- `Price` is almost certainly a number, so single quotes are not needed.
- The `ELSE` can save problems if you have a typo.  If the list in the `CASE` doesn't match the `WHERE`, then this will not `update` other rows.
- Dates should be stored as dates, and comparison values should use standard formats -- YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 0):

You just need one `case` expression :

```
update [Test$ABC]
Set [Unit Price] =(CASE WHEN [Item No_] = '12345' THEN '445'
                        WHEN [Item No_] = '67890' THEN '645'
                   END)
where [Item No_] in ('12345','67890') and 
      [Sales Start Date] = '01/Apr/19'and [Store No_] = ''
```

Answer (score 0):

try like below, i think unit price is int data type so i ignored quote there

```
update [Test$ABC]
Set [Unit Price] =(

CASE WHEN [Item No_]= '12345'
 THEN 445   
 else 645  
END

)    
where [Item No_] in ('12345','67890')
and [Sales Start Date]='01/Apr/19'
and [Store No_]=''
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the syntax for SQL SERVER CASE statement,

CASE should begins keyword 'CASE' and ends with Keyword 'END'

For your code :

remove case in below line

--CASE WHEN [Item No_]= '67890' THEN '645'

/****************************************/

CASE expression

WHEN value_1 THEN result_1

WHEN value_2 THEN result_2

...
   WHEN value_n THEN result_n

ELSE result

END

/****************************************/

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect syntax, your code should be like

```
UPDATE [Test$ABC]
SET [Unit Price] = CASE [Item No_] WHEN '12345' THEN '445'
                                   WHEN '67890' THEN '645'
                   END

where [Item No_] in ('12345','67890')
and [Sales Start Date]='01/Apr/19'
and [Store No_]=''
```

Please visit and read **[`CASE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** from the docs online.